# IIS rewrite rule with curly brackets

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a rewrite rule like so, but I can't get it to rewrite with the () inside the url, I presume i'm doing something wrong.

```
<rule name="Redirect fitness-industry">
    <match url="^subjects/fitness-industry/active-iq-certificate-in-fitness-instructing-(gym)/level-2" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
</rule>
```

Thank you in advance for any help!
Conor

Comment: replace `(gym)` with `([a-z]+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
\([a-z]+\)
```

Adding `\` before the brackets was the solution!